# How to override the default direct update popup of mfp 8.0 with ionic v3 alert dialog

Tags: ionic3, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to call the directUpdateContext.start() function from the handler of Ionic alert dialog box. For this I passed the context from directUpdate.js file to appcomponent.ts file where am presenting the alert but the directUpdateData and directUpdateContext are passed as undefined.

wldirectupdate.js file.

```
var objectData;
var objectContext;


function wlCommonInit() {
console.log(">> wlCommonInit()...");
    wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData,directUpdateContext) {
        objectData = directUpdateData;
        objectContext = directUpdateContext;
        console.log(">>>> Inside wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler function",directUpdateData,directUpdateContext);
        //console.log(">>>> JSON Inside wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler function",JSON.parse(directUpdateData),JSON.parse(directUpdateContext));
        navigator.notification.confirm(
            'Hello World Update',
            function(buttonIndex) {
                if(buttonIndex == 1){
                    directUpdateContext.start();
                }else{
                    wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                }
            },
            'Custom Dialog title text',
            ['Update']
        );
    };
    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken()
    .then(
        function(){
            console.log('********Obtained token successfully');
        },
        function(){
            console.log("*****Failed obtaining token");
        }
    );
}
```

appcomponent.ts

```
declare var objectData;
declare var objectContext;
presentAlert() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Update Available',
  message: 'Click on the update button to download the latest version',
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Update',
    handler: () => {
      console.log(">>>> Handler function alert");
      objectContext.start();
    }
  }]
});
alert.present();
```

}

Here the objectContext value is get as undefined.
How to pass the context properly to and back from js and ts vice- versa? How to implement this use-case?

Comment: Where is the code where you have passed the objectcontext?

Comment: I think we can directly access those variables declared at top using
declare var objectData and declare var objectContext in appcomponent.ts.
Initially I passed those through a function but now am trying to directly access those.

Comment: Is that possible ?

Comment: Can you try directly  overriding  wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate  in appcomponent.ts